# Scala iterable set and sameElements

Tags: scala, set, iterable

I am currently working on the exercises for Scala at https://www.scala-exercises.org/std_lib/iterables.

The last example illustrates the use of `sameElements` with these examples

```
val xs1 = Set(3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7)
val ys1 = Set(7, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3)
println(xs1 sameElements ys1) //true
```

and then

```
val xt1 = Set(1, 2, 3)
val yt1 = Set(3, 2, 1)
println(xt1 sameElements yt1) // false
```

Why is `Set(3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7) sameElements Set(7, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3) == true`, but `Set(1, 2, 3) sameElements Set(3, 2, 1)` is `false`? I know that the order of elements matters. But what is the logic behind the order of these sets?